# Removing expressions from exponentials

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation

I have this expression:
$$\exp(E_f/kt) = \exp(Ev_1/kt) / \exp(Ev_2/kt)$$
In the equation after this, all the $kt$
terms are removed and we are left with:
$$\exp(E_f) = \exp(Ev_1) / \exp(Ev_2)$$
How is that possible? What property did he use?

Comment: There is no such algebraic property.  Was there another part of the exercise that showed that "kt= 1"?

Comment: No. So i guess this is an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_f = a, kt = b, Ev_1 = c, Ev_2 = d$

So, $$e^{a/b} = \frac{e^{c/b}}{e^{d/b}}$$

$$(e^a)^{1/b} = \bigg(\frac{e^c}{e^d}\bigg)^{1/b}$$

[As, $x^{yz} = (x^y)^z$, $z = 1/b$]

$$(e^a) = \frac{e^c}{e^d}$$

So, $$\exp(E_f) = \frac{\exp(Ev_1)}{\exp(Ev_2)}$$

Comment: Thanks! But this wouldnt work if there were some factor to a certain part of the equation right? For example, if it were: exp(Ef/kt)=0.5exp(Ev1/kt)/exp(Ev2/kt). Notice the 0.5? If this were the expression, then it could nt be done, right?

Comment: I have added some lines for you!

Comment: Yes but in that case, $$0.5 = e^{\ln(0.5)} = (e^{kt\ln(0.5)})^{1/kt}$$

Comment: Excellent asnwer, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can write $$\frac{e^{\frac{Ev_1}{kt}}}{e^{\frac{Ev_2}{kt}}}=e^{\frac{Ev_1}{kt}-\frac{Ev_2}{kt}}=e^{\frac{E}{kt}(v_1-v_2)}$$ so we get
$$e^{\frac{E_f}{kt}}=e^{\frac{E}{kt}(v_1-v_2)}$$
and we obtain
$$\frac{E_f}{kt}=\frac{E}{kt}(v_1-v_2)$$ thus $$E_f=E(v_1-v_2)$$

Comment: But how all the kt parts were removed?

Comment: They can not be removed!

Comment: Because $kt$ is a common denominator of both sides:$$\frac az =\frac bz \iff az=bz \implies a=b$$ so long as $z\neq 0$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
e^{\frac{E_f}{kt}}=\frac{e^{\frac{Ev_1}{kt}}}{e^{\frac{Ev_2}{kt}}}=e^{\frac{Ev_1-Ev_2}{kt}}
\end{equation}
Then, it can be written
\begin{equation}
e^{E_f}=e^{Ev_1-Ev_2}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Just raise both sides to the $(kt)^\text{th}$ power. It’s that simple!